# Duplicating prime numbers of even numbers

Tags: java, primes

This part of an assignment requires to check every even number in an array for 2 prime numbers that add up to that even number. I already managed to find all the primes between 2 and each even number and put those primes in a separate array list. I've already found how to find 2 prime numbers that add up to each even number; however when I check the output, it gives me multiple answers like this:

```
    How many numbers would you like to compute: 
    12
    Your two prime factors that add up to 4 are: 
    2 & 2
    Your two prime factors that add up to 6 are: 
    3 & 3
    Your two prime factors that add up to 8 are: 
    3 & 5
    Your two prime factors that add up to 8 are: 
    5 & 3
    Your two prime factors that add up to 10 are: 
    3 & 7
    Your two prime factors that add up to 10 are: 
    5 & 5
    Your two prime factors that add up to 12 are: 
    5 & 7
    Your two prime factors that add up to 12 are: 
    7 & 5
```

All I want is ONE pair of primes that sum up to each even number in a loop. My code looks like this:

```
    //For Loop looks at every even number in the arrayList
    //for(int c = 0; c < len; c++) {

        //Code for Numbers that come before every even number
        //Code for Finding primes


        //Finding prime numbers that add up to even number
        int len3 = primeNumbers.size();
        for(int f = 0; f < len3; f++) {
            if(primeNumbers.get(f) + primeNumbers.get(f) == index) {
                System.out.println("Your two prime factors that add up to " + index + " are: ");
                System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(f) + " & " + primeNumbers.get(f));
                break;
            }   


            for(int g = 1; g < len3; g++) {
                if(primeNumbers.get(f) + primeNumbers.get(g) == index) {
                    System.out.println("Your two prime factors that add up to " + index + " are: ");
                    System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(f) + " & " + primeNumbers.get(g));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your second loop should start from f. So if you do that u can remove the first if you have and then have this. I havent tested it. But try and let me know if it works.

```
for(int f = 0; f < len3; f++) {
    for(int g = f; g < len3; g++) {
        if(primeNumbers.get(f) + primeNumbers.get(g) == index) {
            System.out.println("Your two prime factors that add up to " + index + " are: ");
            System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(f) + " & " + primeNumbers.get(g));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I managed to change your edit so it could also look at the same primes that can add up to the even number like my previous code except i put the secondary loop under the main F loop like yours. Then I "labeled" the main loop like "outer loops:" i wanted to break out of because I figured it out. The index cannot repeat. Anyways,  thanks alot for your help!

Comment: If you could mark this as your answer, it would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call break statement it simply break current loop if your method only handle this logic simply change break statement to return. Hope this is you expect :

```
    int len3 = primeNumbers.size();
    for (int f = 0; f < len3; f++) {
        if (primeNumbers.get(f) + primeNumbers.get(f) == index) {
            System.out.println("Your two prime factors that add up to " + index + " are: ");
            System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(f) + " & " + primeNumbers.get(f));
            return;
        }
        for (int g = 1; g < len3; g++) {
            if (primeNumbers.get(f) + primeNumbers.get(g) == index) {
                System.out.println("Your two prime factors that add up to " + index + " are: ");
                System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(f) + " & " + primeNumbers.get(g));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```